# How to make HA Heartbeat failover when either of two NICs connection is lost?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, heartbeat, failover

I was successful in configuring a simple Heartbeat setup on Ubuntu 12.04, which will fail-over two VIPs to a second server when BOTH Ethernet links fail. What I can't figure out is how to fail-over two VIPs when either of the two NICs loses a link connection.

Heartbeat will detect the link is down, but until both go down, resources will not fail-over. I'm not using any cluster management like Pacemaker.

I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: please post your `ha.cf` and `haresources`.

Comment: Without additional info we cannot assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact configuration this question is hard to answer, but why do you expect the VIPs to fail over?
The link loss is handled by the multipathing dæmon, if both your VIPs are bonded to two NICs.